# Rails 3.2, handle corrupted request bodies (MultiJson::DecodeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rack

I'm working on a Rails 3.2.11 application (MRI 1.9.3).
PArt of it is a webservice that receives POST requests with JSON serialized bodies.
Everything works, but I want it to be resilient to bad formatted requests, e.g. invalid JSON.

Right now, if it receives a JSON with – let's say – a missing comma, it will return a 500 error with an HTML response containing the default rails error view (plus the backtrace when in dev).
I want to customize it to return a JSON or XML response with info about the error.

The error is `MultiJson::DecodeError` and I know I can trap exceptions with [`rescue_from`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#rescue_from) in the ApplicationController... but it doesn't seem to work.
It's like if the error happened **outside** of the normal request flow.

This is my code (once I get it working I'll expand the error message with more data):

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  #protect_from_forgery
  rescue_from MultiJson::DecodeError do |exception|
    @response = { :error => "the request body was not acceptable" }
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to :root, notice: "invalid params" }
        format.xml { render :xml => @response, status: 400 }
        format.json { render :json => @response, status: 400 }
    end
  end
end
```

And this is the backtrace:

```
MultiJson::DecodeError (795: unexpected token at '{
    "json_with_missing_comma" : {
        "foo" : "qqqqqqqqqqqqqqq"
        "bar" : "aaaaaaaaaaaaaa"
    }}'):
  json (1.7.6) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
  json (1.7.6) lib/json/common.rb:155:in `parse'
  multi_json (1.5.0) lib/multi_json/adapters/json_common.rb:7:in `load'
  multi_json (1.5.0) lib/multi_json.rb:96:in `load'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/json/decoding.rb:15:in `decode'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:47:in `parse_formatted_parameters'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:210:in `context'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:341:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.11) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:479:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__1562301902235545482__call__1964551201027599208__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:32:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:22:in `tagged'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.11) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.11) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/application.rb:223:in `call'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
  thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:81:in `block in pre_process'
  thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `catch'
  thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:79:in `pre_process'
  thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:54:in `process'
  thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/connection.rb:39:in `receive_data'
  eventmachine (1.0.0) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
  eventmachine (1.0.0) lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
  thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/backends/base.rb:63:in `start'
  thin (1.5.0) lib/thin/server.rb:159:in `start'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
  rack (1.4.4) lib/rack/server.rb:268:in `start'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands/server.rb:70:in `start'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands.rb:55:in `block in <top (required)>'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `tap'
  railties (3.2.11) lib/rails/commands.rb:50:in `<top (required)>'
  script/rails:6:in `require'
  script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The gem: https://github.com/kares/request_exception_handler along with below lines works for me.

In Application controller:
"
  rescue_from 'REXML::ParseException' do |exception|
    render :text => "Bad Request: XML parse exception", :status => 422
  end

rescue_from 'MultiJson::DecodeError' do |exception|
    render :text => "Bad Request: JSON parse exception", :status => 422
  end
"