# (JSON::ParserError) "{N}: unexpected token at 'alihack<%eval request(\"alihack.com\")%>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the website on Ruby on Rails 3.2.11 and Ruby 1.9.3.

What can cause the following error:

```
(JSON::ParserError) "{N}: unexpected token at 'alihack<%eval request(\"alihack.com\")%>
```

I have several errors like this in the logs. All of them tries to eval request(\"alihack.com\").

Part of the log file:

```
"REMOTE_ADDR" => "10.123.66.198",
"REQUEST_METHOD" => "PUT",
"REQUEST_PATH" => "/ali.txt",
"PATH_INFO" => "/ali.txt",
"REQUEST_URI" => "/ali.txt",
"SERVER_PROTOCOL" => "HTTP/1.1",
"HTTP_VERSION" => "HTTP/1.1",
"HTTP_X_REQUEST_START" => "1407690958116",
"HTTP_X_REQUEST_ID" => "47392d63-f113-48ba-bdd4-74492ebe64f6",
"HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO" => "https",
"HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PORT" => "443",
"HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR" => "23.27.103.106, 199.27.133.183".
```

199.27.133.183 - is CLoudFlare IP.
"REMOTE_ADDR" => "10.93.15.235" and "10.123.66.198" and others, I think, are fake IPs of proxy.

Here's [a link](https://github.com/bcyc/website/issues/37) guy has the same issue with his web site from the same ip address(23.27.103.106).

To sum up, the common ip from all errors is 23.27.103.106 and they try to run the script using ruby's eval.

So my questions are:
What type of vulnerability they try to find?
What to do? Block the ip?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Getting this too.  Any ideas?  I guess it's a good thing that we actually see it.

Comment: I'm getting this as well from a different IP address. It comes alongside other very suspicious requests like ones to `path="/admin/fckeditor/editor/filemanager/connectors/php/upload.php"` I think it's just someone running some attack tool on a ton of domains

Comment: I'm also getting those requests from a couple of days ago from a different IP address

Answer (score 65, accepted):

### Why it happens?

It seems like an attempt to at least test for, or exploit, a remote code execution vulnerability. Potentially a generic one (targeting a platform other than Rails), or one that existed in earlier versions.

The actual error however stems from the fact that the request is an `HTTP PUT` with `application/json` headers, but the body isn't a valid json.

### To reproduce this on your dev environment:

`curl -D - -X PUT --data "not json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" http://localhost:3000`

### More details

Rails action_dispatch tries to parse any json requests by passing the body to be decoded

```
  # lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb

  def parse_formatted_parameters(env)
    ...
    strategy = @parsers[mime_type]
    ...

    case strategy
    when Proc
      ...
    when :json
      data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(request.body)
    ...
```

In this case, it's not a valid JSON, and the error is raised, causing the server to report a 500.

### Possible solutions

I'm not entirely sure what's the best strategy to deal with this. There are several possibilities:

1. you can block the IP address using `iptables`
2. filter (`PUT` or all) requests to `/ali.txt` within your `nginx` or `apache` configs.
3. use a tool like the [`rack-attack`](https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack) gem and apply the filter there. (see this [rack-attack issue](http://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack/issues/99) )
4. use the [`request_exception_handler`](https://github.com/kares/request_exception_handler) gem to catch the error and handle it from within Rails (See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14761810/305019) and [this github issue](https://github.com/puma/puma/issues/286))
5. <s>block `PUT` requests within Rails' `routes.rb` to all urls but those that are explicitly allowed. It looks like that in this case, the error is raised even before it reaches Rails' routes - so this might not be possible.</s>
6. Use the [`rack-robustness`](https://github.com/blambeau/rack-robustness) middleware and catch the json parse error with something like [this configuration](https://gist.github.com/gingerlime/18f1a64a4c2a252ca766) in `config/application.rb`
7. Write your own middleware. Something along the lines of the stuff on [this post](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/catching-json-parse-errors-with-custom-middleware)

I'm currently leaning towards options #3, #4 or #6. All of which might come in handy for other types of bots/scanners or other invalid requests that might pop-up in future...

Happy to hear what people think about the various alternative solutions

Comment: The right answer depends on how you want to handle it. It's not an application-specific concern, so writing code or middleware into your app to deal with this is probably wrong. (That is, if you were running several apps on the same server, you would want all of them protected against this attack.) So this would probably go on `iptables` on your load balancer, or something similar, and I prefer solutions [1] and [2] for that reason.

Comment: Thanks John. I see where you're coming from. It's true that other solutions are more application-specific. On the other hand, solutions [1] and [2] are very attack-specific. i.e. any other request with malformed JSON to a different URL or from a different IP won't be covered by those... Whereas rescuing from any JSON ParseError and logging it would.

Comment: If you want to use rack-attack you might need this for rails: https://github.com/kickstarter/rack-attack/issues/99

Answer (score 10):

I saw some weird log entries on my own site [which doesn't use Ruby] and Google took me to this thread.  The IP on my entries was different.  [120.37.236.161]

After poking around a bit more, here is my mostly speculation/educated guess:

First, in my own logs I saw a reference to http://api.alihack.com/info.txt - checked this link out; looked like an attempt at a PHP injection.

There's also a "register.php" page there - submitting takes you to an "invite.php" page.

Further examination of this domain took me to http://www.alihack.com/2014/07/10/168.aspx (page is in Chinese but Google Translate helped me out here)

I expect this "Black Spider" tool has been modified by script kiddies and is being used as a carpet bomber to attempt to find any sites which are "vulnerable."

It might be prudent to just add an automatic denial of any attempt including the "alihack" substring to your configuration.

Comment: This is definitely ERB syntax `<%eval request(\"alihack.com\")%>` so it seems they must be going after Rails vulnerabilities too.

Comment: "It might be prudent to just add an automatic denial of any attempt including the "alihack" substring to your configuration." ⇒ This is almost certainly a terrible idea. See, e.g., **[the Scunthorpe problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem)**.

Comment: hey @JohnFeminella! nice bumping into you :) I totally agree it's a bad idea. I'm curious about your thoughts / opinion about the possible alternatives I suggested on my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25487047/305019).

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue show up in my Rollbar logs, a PUT request to /ali.txt

Best just to block that IP, I only saw one request on my end with this error. The request I received came from France -> http://whois.domaintools.com/37.187.74.201

If you use nginx, add this to your nginx conf file;

```
deny 23.27.103.106/32;
deny 199.27.133.183/32;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know what type of vulnerability they are trying to find?

Comment: Can you deny this if your app is on Heroku?

Comment: For heroku I would recommend to use service called CloudFlare. It helps you resolve issues like hacking attacks and blocking the ips. You use it as a firewall for your site

Answer (score 0):

For Rails-3 there is a special workaround-gem: https://github.com/infopark/robust_params_parser