# "Invalid JSON primitive: alihack" errors coming from an ASP.NET MVC site

Tags: asp.net, iis, cracking

We started to get multiple such errors daily, appearing in the Event Log:

> Invalid JSON primitive: alihack. at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()
>   at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32
>   depth) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String
>   input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer) at
>   System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer
>   serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetDeserializedObject(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderFactoryCollection.GetValueProvider(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.get_ValueProvider() at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ParameterDescriptor parameterDescriptor) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValues(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__19(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object
>   state) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1c(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__14(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object callbackState, Controller controller) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.BeginExecute(RequestContext
>   requestContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__4(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) at
>   Orchard.Mvc.Routes.ShellRoute.HttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

The requests go to http://example.com/ali.txt. There should be something else in the request's payload since simply opening this URL correctly results in a 404.

Is this something to worry about? Can I, should I prevent such an error from happening and instead return a Bad Request for example? Why is this de-serialization happening in the first place?

Comment: The one downvoting could really explain it.

Comment: I'm noticing the same issue in our ELMAH logs. I'm trying to track it down now.

Comment: Great, let me know if you found something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This issue is a duplicate of [(JSON::ParserError) "{N}: unexpected token at 'alihack<%eval request(\"alihack.com\")%>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25274125/jsonparsererror-n-unexpected-token-at-alihackeval-request-alihack-c) but for a different server (IIS).

If your site does not use PUT requests you can simply deny all of those by using [`<requestFiltering />`](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering).

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <requestFiltering>
          <verbs applyToWebDAV="false">
            <add verb="PUT" allowed="false" />
          </verbs>
        </requestFiltering>
      </security>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Otherwise a more elegant solution can be archieved with the [url rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) (can be installed with the [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx)):

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Abort requests to ali.txt - alihack" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="ali.txt" />
          <conditions />
          <action type="AbortRequest" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Since you are not using a wildcard, you can use ```patternSyntax="ExactMatch"```

Answer (score 1):

There is a more general issue here at play: Asp.Net MVC (.Net Framework) fails with a 500 HTTP error when it receives a request with a JSON content type which has not valid JSON in its payload.

That is a bad handling of this case by Asp.Net MVC. It should simply reply a Bad Request (HTTP 400) in this case.

Unfortunately I do not know of an easy way to fix that bad handling for the general case.

In my case, I have put the following code in the application `IExceptionFilter`:

```cs
/// <inheritdoc />
public virtual void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    // Custom errors are not enabled, let the error bubble up.
    if (!filterContext.HttpContext.IsCustomErrorEnabled)
        return;

    // Detect .Net Framework failures on bad requests.
    if (filterContext.Exception is ArgumentException argEx)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext?.Request?.ContentType?.ToLowerInvariant().Contains("json") ?? false)
        {
            // Check if it seems to be a request with an invalid JSON payload.
            var callStack = argEx.StackTrace;
            if (callStack.Contains("System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize") &&
                callStack.Contains("System.Web.Mvc.JsonValueProviderFactory.GetDeserializedObject") &&
                callStack.Contains("System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.GetParameterValue"))
            {
                filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Invalid JSON");
                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    // Other error cases handling code goes here.
}
```

That is clearly a crutch, though... And the error handling shown here may not be suitable for your application. Mine uses IIS `httpErrors` to output an adequate error page.